# Using Jenkins JBoss plugin

Tags: java, jboss, jenkins

I can't really find how to use **Jenkins' jboss plugin**. I went through things what are obvious, but for example I have no clue how to use the component, adding what properties etc.

I want to deploy an EAR and multiple WARs, and I have problem even with start JBoss. I realized that JBoss 7 won't run, it simply supports earlier version. I got it, and I bumped to 15 sec timeout.

Comment: so far I am thinking of just a workaround with ant script, I see no great chance to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only make a workaround with ANT. I hope it will be helpful for the next person who thinks that Jenkins' jboss plugin works... it isn't with the v7.1.1 for sure.

So the workaround:

Check if JBoss responds

```
  <condition property="jboss.online">
    <socket server="localhost" port="8080"/>
  </condition>
```

If yes, stop JBoss and delete all deployments

```
<target name="stop" depends="-check-status" if="${start.successful}">
    <java jar="${jboss.home}/jboss-modules.jar" fork="true">
        <arg line="-mp ${jboss.home}/modules org.jboss.as.cli -c command=:shutdown" />
    </java>

    <sleep seconds="10" />
    <delete quiet="false" includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments/">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

Copy all ears and wars to deployments

```
            <copy file="${publish.dir}/main.ear" overwrite="true" todir="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments" />
        <copy file="${publish.dir}/first.war" overwrite="true" todir="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments" />
        <copy file="${publish.dir}/second.war" overwrite="true" todir="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments" />
```

Start JBoss

```
<exec executable="${jboss.home}/bin/standalone.bat" spawn="true">
```

Wait for deployments and start unit tests

```
<!-- startup, deploy -->
<target name="deploy-war" description="deploy war file" depends="-start">
    <condition property="jboss.online">
        <socket server="localhost" port="8080"/>
    </condition>

    <echo message="${jboss.online}"> ONLINE STATUS</echo>
  <sequential>
    <echo>WAITING FOR DEPLOYMENT...</echo>
    <waitfor>
        <or>
            <available file="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments/main.ear.deployed" />
            <available file="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments/main.ear.failed" />
        </or>
    </waitfor>
    <condition property="deployed">
        <available file="${jboss.home}/standalone/deployments/main.ear.deployed" />
    </condition>

    <antcall target="deploy.failed"/>
    <antcall target="deploy.success"/>

    <echo>+----------------------------+</echo>
    <echo>|   W A R  D E P L O Y E D   |</echo>
    <echo>+----------------------------+</echo>

  </sequential>
</target>

<!-- Deploy success, run unit tests -->
 <target name="deploy.success" if="deployed">
   <echo>DEPLOY SUCCESS</echo>
    <sleep seconds="10" />
    <antcall target="unit-test.-multi-only-unit-test-noreport"></antcall>
 </target>

<!-- Deploy failed, fail -->
 <target name="deploy.failed" unless="deployed">
   <echo>DEPLOY FAILED</echo>
    <fail/>
 </target>
```

if anything fails call an ant error, so Jenkins will send mail about the error.

When I refactor my code I will post the final version